# Can paypal credit card payment be handled in a hosted page like paypal express?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

For paypal express payment (the one pay via a paypal account), I am quite happy to provide a return url and handle the payment in a paypal page. (so the transaction doesn't happen in my site).

If I want to accept credit card payments, I saw some APIs that I can pass credit card number from my site to paypal. Is it possible that I can just provide a return url and go to a paypal page? On that page, my user can type in credit card number and payment details. So I won't have to worry if my site is secure with those financial data.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following parameters to your SetExpressCheckout request and I think you'll get what you're wanting.

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Also, make sure you have the VERSION set to 119.0.